# How do I validate a form that doesnt go to another page yet fills out another form on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two forms on a page, the second form should be filled out and have validation required to fill out most of the input fields. If the fields arent filled out, then a pop-up or alert should be shown once the save button has been clicked, notifying the user of what needs to be done.

Once the saved button has been clicked, the correctly filled out textfields should be copied/transferred/moved to the first form. For example; in the second form if I fill out title, name and surname. Those three fields need to be validated. Once I hit the save-button, the values in the title, name and surname field should be concatenated inside of the name textfield in the first form.

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted to issues with your code:

- if you want to `var a = document.forms["forms"]["Title"].value;` then "forms" value must be set on the `id` attribute instead of `name`attribute.
- `document.getElementById('name').innerText =` won't change the value of the name input, you have to use the `value` property instead.

Corrected code snippet below

```js
function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("save-btn").onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateForm();
    moveContent();
}

function moveContent() {
    var x = document.getElementById('name').value =
        document.getElementById('TitleTransfer').value + ' ' +
        document.getElementById('NameTransfer').value + ' ' +
        document.getElementById('LastNameTransfer').value;
}

function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["forms"]["Title"].value;
    var b = document.forms["forms"]["NameTransfer"].value;
    var c = document.forms["forms"]["LastNameTransfer"].value;
    var d = document.forms["forms"]["EmailTransfer"].value;
    if (a == null || a == "", b == null || b == "", c == null || c == "", d == null || d == "") {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
        return false;
    }
}

function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```html
<h1>Your Name and Address</h1>
<form action="/">
    <div class="nameDiv">
        Name: <input type="textbox" name="firstname" title="name" id="name">

        <div class="dotOne"> ? </div>
        <span class="nameHelp"> Please enter first and last name   </span>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="addressDiv">
        Address: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="address">
        <div class="dotTwo">?</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="emailDiv">
        Email:
        <input type="text" name="Email" id="email">
        <span class="dotThree">?</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="numberDiv">
        Phone number:
        <input type="text" name="Phone number" id="number">
        <span class="dotFour">?</span>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
<button class="btn" onclick="openForm()">Edit Details</button>

<div id="container">
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Name', this, 'grey')" id="defaultOpen">Name</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Address', this, 'grey')">Address</button>

    <div id="Name" class="tabcontent">

        <form id="forms">
            <div class="nameDiv">
                Title: <input type="text" name="Title" title="Title" id="TitleTransfer">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="addressDiv">
                Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="NameTransfer">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="emailDiv">
                Surname:
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="LastNameTransfer">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="numberDiv">
                Email Address:
                <input type="text" name="email Address" id="EmailTransfer">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="numberDiv">
                Phone number:
                <input type="text" name="Phone number" id="NumberTransfer">
            </div>
            <button id="save-btn" onclick="validateForm()">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="Address" class="tabcontent">
        <form>
            <div class="nameDiv">
                Line 1: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey" title="name" class="name">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="addressDiv">
                Line 2: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse" class="address">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="emailDiv">
                Suburb:
                <input type="text" name="Email" value="Email" class="email">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="numberDiv">
                State:
                <input type="text" name="Phone number" value="Phone number" class="number">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="numberDiv">
                Country:
                <input type="text" name="Phone number" value="Phone number" class="number">
            </div>
            <button class="save-btn" onclick="">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

As asked by the author, this is a working fiddle implementation of the problem, with the css provided in another fiddle by the author, where the second form dissappear after having clicked "save".

[Working fiddle with the css](http://jsfiddle.net/t6hz4512/5/)

Comment: What didn't work? With the code above, if you fill the second form and click save, the content of the fields is concatenated and copied to the name input of the first form. Wasn't it what was intended?

Comment: yes that is what I wanted. But when I run it on my end including the css. It does not work....

Comment: Can you provide the css included and describe how it's not working? Also, did you manage to successfully run my snippet ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2zvkmhxr/8/ .  yes I did but I cant get my to work because I use a css sheet with mine.

Comment: The css is not what's causing the issue. You also had two errors in the fiddle:
same as in the snippet `name="forms"` instead of `id="forms"` and the `validateForms` function was missing. Follow the link at the end of my answer for a working fiddle.

Comment: It still doesnt work... the second form has to dissappear... when I hit the save button aswell... :(

Comment: Andrew you never said that the second form should disapear, there was no code doing it, and your original issue has been fixed.
Still, I'm a good sport, so I've updated the fiddle to make the second form disapear by the use of `document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";`at the end of moveContent.
Cheers